# Cannot hide link

Tags: css

I'm trying to hide the text of this content:

```
<div class="avrow"><a href="http://www.altervista.org" class="avlink disclaimer">Powered by Altervista Mailing List</a></div>
```

I tried:

```
.avrow > .avlink disclaimer > a
{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

not seems to working anyway, how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `a` tag has the class `.avlink` and `.disclaimer`. So the order of your CSS is wrong and if you have 2 classes on one element, you will need to append both class names.

```css
.avrow > a.avlink.disclaimer {
  display:none;
 }
```

```html
<div class="avrow"><a href="http://www.altervista.org" class="avlink disclaimer">Powered by Altervista Mailing List</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hidde an specific element, you can try the next ones:
By Css

```
display: none
```

By HTML´s tag:

```
<div hidden>Your element, could be others elements as well</div>
```

Comment: the text: Powered by Altervista is even visible

Comment: Strange... Did you clean your browser cache after change css style? I´m gonna try in my computer and then I let you know...

Comment: @AgainMe It works... I´m supposing, but maybe you css file is so extensive (that could be a problem, when you are refreshing it...), you should clean your browser´s cache...

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the .avlink class is not a child of a, but at the same level.

The following will achieve what you're going for:

```
.avrow > a.avlink
{
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

See http://jsbin.com/holivirofe/edit?html,css,js,output for a working example.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:

```
.avrow {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There two common ways of hiding elements in CSS. The first is the [visibility](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) property that you have been using. This simply hides the element but maintains it's properties such as size and margins. Therefore it has the effect of looking like it is not "hiding" the element correctly.

The other way is using the [display](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) property. By setting the display property to hidden it efectively renders the HTML as if the element is not there. This means the other elements are not affected by the hidden one.

Also your css selector is incorrect, it suggests there should be an anchor element below `.avlink`. Your selector should actually be:

```
.avrow>a.avlink.disclaimer
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.avrow > a
{
 visibility: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also take one of the class names like I did below.

```css
.disclaimer {
 display: none;
}


.disclaimer {
 visibility: hidden
}
```